# Dynamically Control Page Navigation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I’m creating an ASP.NET MVC 4 Application that needs to have dynamic page navigation (based on the users input parameters – they will navigate certain web pages in a certain order).  I’m attempting to control the user’s navigation by creating a “navigation” object after the user specifies their input parameters.  As the user navigates the application, navigation.getNextPage() allows me to send the user to the next page of the application.  Each user should only have one instance of the navigation object (i.e. a singleton for their interaction with the application).

The challenge I’m having is keeping the navigation object alive throughout the life of the application instance.  I can’t create a static singleton because static members are shared across all instances of the application (and each user’s navigation order will be different).  I tried storing a navigation object in HttpContext.Current.Items but the object only seems to live for a single request (and constantly putting/pulling from [tempData] across all my controllers is way too hackish and not consistent with good OO principles).

1. How do I “correctly” persist my navigation object across the life of the application instance (i.e. one “interaction” for the user)?
2. Is there a more correct way to achieve dynamic page navigation within ASP.NET MVC 4?

Comment: Why don't you just set a cookie value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the Session object? The main purpose for Session is to store and retrieve values for a user as the user navigates ASP.NET pages in a Web application.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I can use the HttpContext.Current.Session to keep objects alive for the life of a session (the default time period appears to be 20 minutes).